# Aws amplify - what is the best practise of deployment in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using different accounts for environment management by cloudformation.

I am considering the best deployment procedure
There are 2 ways i think of.

1.serverless setup(lambda,dynamodb,s3 etc) in different account, but deployment for different environments(UAT,Prod) is done on the same master account.
E.g.account master_admin for deployment of all environment in amplify. dev_admin and uat_admin are used for serverless setup for dev and uat environment separately.

2.both serverless setup and deployment are done on the same account
E.g.dev_admin is used for serverless setup and amplify deployment in dev stage, while uat_admin is for uat env serverless setup and amplify deployment

I am not sure the pros and cons for these 2 ways and which one is better

Comment: It's complex for having multiple account for each env. Why don't you try using prefix for each resource name e.g for lambda function name would be prod_function_one, staging_function_one, dev_function_one

Answer (score 0):

Creating different accounts for each environment (PRODUCTION, Stage), provide separation between the environments, but operational tasks are challenges.

- create IAM users, groups, and policies for each account.
- sign in to each account separately.
  And you may need to think on:
- AWS Organizations and Consolidated Billing.
- Federate identity.

One account for all environments simplifies managing users and permission but needs IAM Groups, user, roles, and policies in addition tp Resource level policies, for access control,
and aws resources need to be tagged to distinguish between the environments.

Comment: So which one you prefer? Thanks

Comment: For big multi teams environments I would prefer multiple AWS account, otherwise you may go with one AWS account for simplification